# R: Cross-validation with low-sample categorical variables

Tags: r, random, r-caret, cross-validation

I want to perform cross validation in R.

My data has a categorical variable with 80 levels, but some of these levels have only a few representatives (often 10 or less). I want to be sure that my training and test sets all contain enough samples within these low-representative levels of my categorical variable to run correctly.

However, splitting of data in cross validation is often random, so I'm concerned that perhaps low-sample categories won't be well represented in training and test data splitssets.

**Is there a way in R to split my data in a way that ensures that low-frequency levels of a given categorical variable are well distributed between training and test sets?**

---

*Context: I have ~90000 repeated-measures tree growth samples which represent ~80 levels of a categorical variable (species).*

Comment: Search for "stratified random sampling". You will get many hits.

Comment: [This answer on CrossValidated might be helpful](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation).